# Create custom config file with matching xsd file - implement to a class

Tags: c#, configuration, xsd

I searched the web, probably because i didn't write the correct query.
I want to create a custom configuration class that can be configured with a xsd file and when loaded into a program manifest it self as a class. (just like log4net,nLog or any other good open source program). and insert it to VS 2010.
Any link or help will be fine
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to use an xml config file which CONFORMS TO A XSD schema, then

1. Create the xsd file, defining your config xml.
2. Use xsd.exe to generate a class file off your xsd.
3. As @Peyman suggests, use the .net custom configuration framework to integrate the class into your solution as a custom configuration section.

Voila

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyCustomConfig : ConfigurationSectionGroup
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("[Name].ConfigSection")]
    public objectFeedImport
    {
        get { return base.Sections["[Name].ConfigSection"]; }
    }
}


ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = [Custom Config Name];            
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap , ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)


 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="[Name].ConfigGroup" type ="">
       <section name="[Name].ConfigSection" type="" />
     </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
```

Comment: This is from the app.config file if i am not mistaken. please i want an external file supported with xds file.